# Clicking on tab not changing div

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I am coding in JADE, and trying to ensure that when I click on a tab, it changes the screen ( or the information ). Here are all the javascript code I have tried.

```
function showDiv() {
            document.getElementById('tab2').style.display = "block";
        }



 $(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e) {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        if (currentAttrValue == "#tab2")
        {
            $('#tab2').show().siblings().hide();
            $('#tab2').parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }

    });
});


 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
        jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

        // Change/remove current tab to active
        jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

And here is the jade code I have. Currently the first tab is showing the table, whose code I have mostly removed from the segment posted. When I click on tab2 the content of tab2 is not displayed.

```
  tabs
      ul.tab-links
          li.active
            a(href='#tab1') Tab #1

          li
            a(href='#tab2', onclick="showDiv()") Tab #2


      .tab-content
        #tab1.tab.active
          div.row(ng-cloak, style="padding-top: 10px")
            table.table.table-striped
              thead
                tr.text-info
                  th.th-nodecheck
                    i.icon-check-o(data-toggle="tooltip", data-placement="top", title="Pin nodes to display first", ng-click="orderTable(['-stats.block.number', 'stats.block.propagation'], false)")
                  th.th-nodename
                    i.icon-node(data-toggle="tooltip", data-placement="top", title="Node name", ng-click="orderTable(['info.name'], false)")
                  th.th-nodetype
                    i.icon-laptop(data-toggle="tooltip", data-placement="top", title="Node type", ng-click="orderTable(['info.node'], false)")



        #tab2.tab.active
          p Tab #2 content goes here!           
          p
            Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide us with a working code snippet using StackOverflow or JSFiddle?

Comment: In your jade code that first `tabs` should be `.tabs`, right?

Comment: @OliverB  it worked ! Thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem! Have put into an answer so you can mark as solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JADE code has an error - a block marked up as `tabs` where it should be `.tabs`, causing a `<tabs>` element to be output, thus failing to be caught by your `$('.tabs .tab-links a')`. Your JS code was fine!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT- Your existing JS code was fine, but I think this might be a better way of implementing it.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.tab-links').find('a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href'),
            nextTab = currentAttrValue == "#tab2" ? "#tab2" : "#tab1";
        $(nextTab).show().siblings().hide();
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');   
    });
});
```